# Load UIImage from URL in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift3, nsurlrequest, imageurl

I am  trying to load a `UIImage` from its URL with `completion`and `placeholder` image , but neither the `UIImage` nor the placeholder `UIImage` are loaded.

Here is my code:

```
  NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://assets.gearlive.com/tvenvy/blogimages/stewiegriffin.jpg"];
  NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

  [self.imageView setImageWithURLRequest:request placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bg.png"]

      success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image) {
          imageView.image = image;
      } 
      failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {}
   ];
```

Comment: Your code seems correct. Just set the placeholder directly `self.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bg.png"];` to make sure your image view is visible and setting the image works..

Comment: If setting the image directly does not work, set image view's background color `self.imageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];` and run the app to make sure the image view is acually visible on the screen..

Comment: @AdhRadwan i have posted answer try it and inform me.

Comment: Thanks @lukya your comment  is realy  helpful

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use `AFnetworking` where you can set placeholder image also if the url is not correct. This is more efficient when you are loading images in a tableview or a collection view.

Import `UIImageView+AFNetworking.h`

```
#import "UIImageView+AFNetworking.h"
```

and us the following code:

```
NSString *url1=@"http://www.fnordware.com/superpng/pnggrad16rgb.png";
[self.image setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url1] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];
```

You can download it from [gitHub](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking)

Comment: I had used SDImage, never knew AF could do that too...Thanks

Comment: can i able to use image url as placeholder image ?

Comment: For any future devs, the import is no longer necessary.

Answer (score 15):

Try this code to get image...

**Code:**

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.fnordware.com/superpng/pnggrad16rgb.png"];

NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];

[self.imageview1 setImage:image];
```

**Note:** i have used test url. you can use your url.

**Update :** 
**Swift 3.0 Code** :

```
let url = URL(string: "http://www.fnordware.com/superpng/pnggrad16rgb.png")
    do {
        let  data = try Data(contentsOf: url!)
        var image = UIImage(data: data)
        self.imageView.image = image
        print(image)
    } catch {

    }
```

**Note :** In Xcode version 7.1 and above you need to set ATS (App Transport Security). To set ATS you need  write below code in info.plist file.
Make sure url of image should not be nil.

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

Comment: Tested this in Playgrounds, converted to swift 3, and works perfectly! Thanks!

Comment: @Simon Thanks for your feedback i have updated the answer and also added code for swift.

Answer (score 3):

Check out [`AsyncImageView`](https://github.com/nicklockwood/AsyncImageView). Its the best async image loader AFAIK. all you have to do is set the image URL to the imageview and the rest is taken care of. including caching.

Comment: this one is very easy to use

Answer (score 1):

**I found the problem**

> My code is working correctly.

The problem was somewhere in my code , the `ImageView` was `nil`.
Thanks all