# NSData to uiimage return null

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiimageview, uiimage

_pageImages is nsmutableArry I'm store the image url.

```
_pageImages = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"https://api.url2png.com/v3/P4DE5D1C99D8EF/7bbb6e0d1b74fb0ae1d4f18b06320096/400x400/abc.com",@"https://api.url2png.com/v3/P4DE5D1C99D8EF/7bbb6e0d1b74fb0ae1d4f18b06320096/400x400/abc.com", nil];
```

Want to display this url images in uiimageview.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[_pageImages objectAtIndex:i]];

NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];

UIImage *tmpImage = [UIImage imageWithData:data];

_backgroundImageView.frame = CGRectMake(0 ,10, 320, 320);

 _backgroundImageView.image = tmpImage;

  [self.view addSubview:_backgroundImageView];
```

I saw many examples but i can't get the proper solution. new for development. help me..

Comment: Did you checked that your data is not nil ? Cause maybe you just forget to disable App Transport Security for the target domain

( and when I try https://api.url2png.com/v3/P4DE5D1C99D8EF/7bbb6e0d1b74fb0ae1d4f18b06320096/400x400/abc.com myself, i get an error in browser ... )

Comment: Yeah how about using methods that return `NSError` objects (for example `initWithContentsOfURL:options:error:`).

Comment: you can find the anser here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30096806/load-uiimage-from-url-in-ios

Comment: check that your image URL , it shows at wrong

Comment: i change the url but still the is there UIImage *tmpImage = [UIImage imageWithData:data];... tmpImage is return null..

Comment: _backgroundImageView.image = tmpImage; is null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The problem is in the URL!**

Try to access your images URL, all I got is "*Unauthorized*".

Run this sample code, your code, just using a different image address.
Check for the correct image address, and it should run as expected.

```
NSMutableArray *pageImages = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"http://findicons.com/files/icons/1636/file_icons_vs_3/128/url.png",@"http://findicons.com/files/icons/1636/file_icons_vs_3/128/pdf.png", nil];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[pageImages objectAtIndex:0]];

NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];

UIImage *tmpImage = [UIImage imageWithData:data];

_depImage.frame = CGRectMake(0 ,10, 320, 320);
_depImage.image = tmpImage;
```

Comment: i change the url but still the is there UIImage *tmpImage = [UIImage imageWithData:data];... tmpImage is return null.

Comment: _backgroundImageView.image = tmpImage; is null

Answer (score 0):

try this by sending `AsynchronousRequest` for image downloading--

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[_pageImages objectAtIndex:i]];

[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url] queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
    _backgroundImageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
}];
```

Comment: _backgroundImageView.image = tmpImage; is null

Comment: @Saravananr Happy to help you. :)

Answer (score 0):

We can simply use following to Load Image data from URL

```
_backgroundImageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLwithString:urlString]]];
```

No need of Calling a service call here.

Hope it helps..